# How to make menu items different size on different pages

Tags: html, css, web.py

I'm making a blog. I have couple of pages on it:
-Home
-New post
etc.

So i want titles to be different size on those pages. To be specific i want "Home" font-size to be 45 and "New post" font-size to be 24 if the page is "index" and if the page is "new" i want it to be reverse. How to do that? Maybe specify somehow in "base" file? Or i have to somehow alter it in "new" file?

Pictures of the web-site:
[image]
[image]
Here's the code:

__base.html

```
$def with (page)

<html>
<head>
    <title>S. Gera | Vision</title>
<style>
    #menu {
        width: 200px;
        float: right;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a style="font-size: 45; text-decoration: none" href="/">Home</a></li>
<li><a style="font-size: 24; text-decoration: none" href="/new">New Post</a></li>
</ul>

$:page

</body>
</html>
```

__index.html

```
$def with (posts)

<html>
<h1 style="color: Grey; font-family: Georgia; text-align: Left">Blog posts</h1>

<ul>
$for post in posts:
    <li>
        <strong> <a style="color: Black; text-decoration: none; font-size: 18" href="/view/$post.id">$post.title</a> </strong>
        <a style="color: Blue; font-size: 15">| $datestr(post.posted_on)</a>
        <a style="color: Red; font-size: 11; font-family: Arial; text-decoration: none" href="/edit/$post.id">(Edit)</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</html>
```

__new.html

```
$def with (form)

<html>
<h1 style="color: Grey; font-family: Georgia; text-align: Left">New Blog Post</h1>

<form action="" method="post">
$:form.render()
</form>
<html>
```

__view.html

```
$def with (post)

<h1>$post.title</h1>
$datestr(post.posted_on)<br/>

$post.content
```

__edit.html

```
$def with (post, form)

<html>
<h1>Edit $form.d.title</h1>

<form action="" method="post">
$:form.render()
</form>


<h2>Delete post</h2>
<form action="/delete/$post.id" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete post"/>
</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a common base, yet do different things based on which template is being used, you'll want to parameterize base, and set the value you want in the template file & have it used in the base.

For example, consider having base be altered such that each menu item will take a class. If `page.selected_menu` matches, then it sets the class to `active`, otherwise, the class is set to `""`.

```
=== base.html ===
...
<ul id="menu">
<li>
   <a class="$('active' if page.selected_menu == 'home' else '')"  
      href="/">Home</a></li>
<li>
   <a class=$('active' if page.selected_menu == 'new' else '')"
      href="/new">New Post</a></li>
</ul>
...
```

Use css to display `ul>li>a.active` differently from `ul>li>a`.

Then, in your templates, set the value for the menu you'd like to be set to "active". For example:

```
=== new.html ===
$var selected_menu: new

=== home.html ===
$var selected_menu: home
```

`var` variables defined in templates are available as attributes within the base template.